# ajax post data is null in controller asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I try to send a JSON object back to the server. This is my AJAX call

```
 function SaveData() {
var model = []
debugger
$.each($('.Money'), function (i, item) {
    model.push({
        Money: $('.Money').eq(i).val(),
        Day: $('.Day').eq(i).val(),
        Note: $('.Note').eq(i).val()
    });
})
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    data: { partnerDeposit: JSON.stringify(model) },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    succsess: function () {
    }
})}
```

This is the method in the controller which is being called:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqEt9.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqEt9.png

The problem I have is that always the json variable from above is an empty object. The success function gets called but when I debug the json var is displayed as empty.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `partnerDeposit` to the `JSON.stringify` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({partnerDeposit: model}),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    succsess: function () {
    }
})
```

Comment: Just noticed that your model isn't a string. In your action method you should change the type of partnerDeposit from string to a List of your object type (an object with money, day and note fields)

Comment: i'm just convert Json to string and pass to controller. but partnerDeposit in controller is null.  i dont no why :(

Comment: asp.net will map your JSON string to C# objects, but as your JSON model can't be mapped to the string in your action, the value is null. You need to create a C# model and change the type in your action from string to List<YourCSharpModelClass>

Comment: I know the problem. because [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] located on myController. when i deleted this. it's work. but I don't know why it's not work with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] =='

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found this answer anywhere else so I had to discover it through experimentation.  Hopefully this will help someone.

1. You'll find that in your controller, it's receiving a Request.Form object and if you look in Request.Form[0] you'll find your data.  The reason that there's data in the form but MVC is seeing it as null is that the key to the form element being POSTed is "" (blank).
2. So client side, you have to set content type properly, and precede your data with something like "myData=" + JSON.stringify(myJSONObject), where "myData" is the key name you are adding, like so:

`$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: "myData="+JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"`

On the server side, your [HttpPost] endpoint has to have as its input a variable with the *same name* as the key you declared in your AJAX, like so:

```
`
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index (string myData) // <-- var name matches AJAX
{
   // de-serialize data into server-side object using 
   // JSONConvert.DeserializeObject
}
```

`